# How does `minmax` create more than one column when passed `1fr` in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Let's say I have the following code. From my understanding, the columns within this grid will never be less than 150 pixels wide... and never more than "1 fraction" of the width of the container.

How then, does the grid decide to create more columns? With this logic, wouldn't you always end up with a grid containing one column that takes up 100% of width of the container?

```css
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.item {
    background: #07c;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With this logic, wouldn't you always end up with a grid containing one column that takes up 100% of width of the container?

No, because the grid will specifically not try to do this when the maximum constraint is expressed in terms of `fr`. Instead, the grid will try to create as many columns that meet the minimum constraint of 150 pixels as the width of the grid container will allow. For example — leaving aside your specified gutter width for a moment — if the grid container is 300 pixels wide, two 150-pixel columns will be created. Should it reach 450 pixels wide, then a third column will be added.

The 1fr means that any remaining space (when the grid container is anywhere between 300 and 450 pixels wide non-inclusive) is distributed equally among the columns, *after* the columns have been laid out.

This is all stated in [section 7.2.2.2 of the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#auto-repeat). The text is rather verbose, but it describes an example that's functionally identical to what you have:

> For example, the following code will create as many 25-character columns as will fit into the window width. If there is any remaining space, it will be distributed among the 25-character columns.
>
> ```css
> body {
>   display: grid;
>   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25ch, 1fr));
> }
> ```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I see I had the order of laying things out wrong. I didn't realise an `fr` unit would change the behaviour of `minmax`.

Comment: `minmax` with `auto-fill`/`auto-fit` will use *max size* to determine track size, if the *max size* is *definite*, which includes `px`, `em`, `%`, etc. Basically, any length that can be determined without performing layout. The *min size* will determine track size when the *max size* is *indefinite*, which includes `auto`, `fr`, `max-content`, etc. Basically, any length that relies on the rendering of the layout first.